# Strip function not working in a list in python

Tags: python, strip

I'd like to remove white spaces before & after each word in a list

```
with open(r"C:\filelocation") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for i in lines:
    i = i.strip()
    i= i.split(",")
```

When I print my list, I get the following

```
['46', 'Celsius  ']
['42', ' Celsius ']
['93', ' Fahrenheit ']
```

I tried i = i.strip() & it doesn't work for my list.

Comment: Nowhere are you modifying your list, so your list doesn't change. Read a tutorial about list manipulation. Also make sure you provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a list of lists, aka **a matrix**. You are **trying to strip each list** using a for-loop, and **you can't really strip a list**.

You have to enumerate through **each item** in **each row**, THEN strip that item.

What you were trying to strip before was:

> ['46', 'Celsius'] # A list

Instead of:

> 'Celsius' # A string

The code is rewritten below:

```py
lines = []
with open('file/location') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Enumerates through each list/row in the matrix.
for row in range(len(lines)):
    # Enumerates through each item in that list
    for column in range(len(row)):
        # Strip each item using its row and column number.
        lines[row][column] = lines[row][column].strip()

print(lines)
```

Result:

> [['46', 'Celsius'], ['42', 'Celsius'], ['93', 'Fahrenheit']]

Answer (score -1):

Seems you want to strip the tokens *after* splitting. Also, you have to reassign the actual list element to make the changes affect the list:

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    lines[i] = [token.strip() for token in line.split(",")]
```

Note that `line` is just a loop variable that is initially referencing the list element. Assigning it another value

```
line = ...
```

will simply bind this variable to a *new* object. The list does *not* get changed by that.